# Is it possible to add to a model field from the frontend without having to invoke a url and template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a Recipe models as follows:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='recipe')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subtitle = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    ingredients = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True,null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True,null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I create instances of this model via a custom form which includes all the fields.

I display all my recipe models in a page called my_account by doing the following in the html page.

```
 {% for recipe in recipes %}
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="{% url 'recipe_details' recipe.category.slug recipe.slug %}" class='field'>{{recipe.title}}</a></td>
                            <td><a href="{% url 'update_recipe' recipe.slug %}" class='button is-dark'>Update</a></td>
                            <td><a href="{% url 'delete_recipe' recipe.slug %}" class='button is-light'>Remove</a></td>
```

My question us basically, can i achieve the following in my_accounts page, where in when the user clicks on add ingredient button, whatever the user has typed in gets **added** to the recipe.ingredients field for that particular recipe.

Example:

if the user types in '1 tbsp sugar' into the input field and clicks Add ingredient, for Black Tea, then '1 tbsp sugar' should get added to ingredients fields for my Black Tea Recipe model instance.
[image]

Comment: Update your Title and be more precise in your description about what thing you actually wanna achieve or your post can be flagged/down voted.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've kind of figured out the problem, not completely but maybe 50-60%.

Firstly, In order to  achieve the desired result, then You'd have to create another model field called "Ingredient" which is linked to the Recipe Model.

Coming too, Retreiving the information that the user has typed in from the front-end.

my_accounts.html page, you'd add the following.

```
 <td>
     <form action= "{% url 'add_ingredient' recipe.slug %}" method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
         <input type="text" value="Add Ingredient"  name="ingredient"><button type="submit">Add Ingredient</button>
     </form>
</td>
```

in the urls.py

```
path('add/<slug:recipe_slug>/', views.add_ingredient, name="add_ingredient"),
```

in the views.py

```
def add_ingredient(request, recipe_slug):

    recipe = get_object_or_404(Recipe, slug=recipe_slug)
    ingredient = request.POST.get('ingredient')
  
    return redirect('my_account')
```